# Android test: instrumentation and with maven build

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, android-instrumentation

I cannot find a tutorial about how to setup Android instrumentation test with Maven build on internet. So, I tried myself with some explorations. I have several questions & problems:

I found pieces of information here and there, but get more confusions. For example, when to execute `mvn:instrument` and when to execute `mvn:deploy`? What is the project structure and how to define the POM for instrumentation, etc.

Anyone can provide me a link about how to setup Android instrumentation test with Maven in steps?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [example projects](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/examples.html) for the Android Maven Plugin for fully running and configured projects.